# Is there any restriction on file size while using arcgis tool box or arcpy methods

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arctoolbox

I am working with ArcToolBox's tools and their python supports. I found there is some restriction on file size of shape files/feature classes etc. It makes me interested to know about is there any restriction with file size on these tools/python methods also? As an example, suppose I am using "Con" method of "Spatial Analyst Tools". Does this method has any size restriction? I read "tool help" document. But I found nothing about file size here.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What questions are you being asked? What tools or methods are you using? What type of databases or files are you working with? Have you tried [searching](http://www.google.com/search?q=size+limitations+%28site:arcgis.com+OR+site%3Aesri.com%29)?

Comment: @blah238 Actually these are not what actually I am searching for. I want to know about the ArcToolBox's tools and their python supports. Such as "Con" method of "Spatial Analyst Tools". Does this method has any size restriction? I read "tool help" document. But I found nothing like that. But as there is some restriction on file size of shape files, feature classes etc., so I thought if there any restriction in those methods also.

Comment: Spatial Analyst implies raster. What type of raster data are you working with?

Comment: @blah238 Now I am working with "file system raster". But I actually want to know the common behavior of these tools. Because I am going to make some add-in that I can use in future. So, its important for me to know does it create problem for any raster/ feature class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This help topic discusses some of the raster format limitations for Spatial Analyst: [Data formats supported by Spatial Analyst](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005900000005000000)

While it is focused mainly on vector overlay operations, [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/06/15/be-successful-overlaying-large-complex-datasets-in-geoprocessing/) has many suggestions, including improvements made at 10.1 and 10.1 SP1. In particular, if you are working with very large datasets, then using [64-bit geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/31/announcing-64-bit-geoprocessing/) at 10.1 SP1 is recommended. Also notable is ESRI's stance (see comments section) on not providing specific numbers regarding internal limitations as there are (allegedly) far too many variables involved.

Beyond that, there is very little that you as a developer can do to ensure that your customers will not have problems processing very large datasets, just as they would without using your custom tool, especially if, as you say, you have to support ANY dataset in ANY format. All bets are off.